# Redirect mobile users loop

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

I have a site that will redirect users to a mobile version of the site if they're browsing on a mobile device. The redirect works fine, but the problem comes when getting them to switch to the desktop version of the site.

If you visit site.com on your mobile, you'll be redirected to m.site2.com (as the mobile version is hosted on a seperate website - confusing I know but it's had to be done this way). Then if the user clicks 'View full site' on m.site2.com, they'll be sent to site.com, but then immediately sent back to m.site2.com.

Is there some code I can put somewhere that specifies if the visitor has come from m.site2.com then it will override the redirect?

This loop is driving me crazy. Also, it has to be in Javascript. If anybody could provide a full script for this I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps setting a query var, or header data can solve Your problem. Checking the referrer can also help.

Comment: Thanks, how would I do that? All I have at the moment is - <script type="text/javascript" src="http://detect.deviceatlas.com/redirect.js?m=http://m.tvrcc.com">
</script>

Comment: The mobile version can redirect to the desktop version like this site.com/redirectedFromAMobieDevice, site.com?redirectedFromAMobieDevice, etc... As for the header data and referrer - google each of them("http headers", "http referrer").

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with Javascript, would you be able to provide the code I'd need to use?

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to redirect to mobile from the server itself. In your case, you are redirecting from the client side, using JavaScript, right?

I have two solutions.

**ONE:** disable automatic redirecting. You can provide a "Desktop Site" link on your mobile version and "Mobile Site" link on your desktop version. If users like, then they can choose mobile or desktop.

**TWO:** create two identical HTML files in your Desktop Site server. Say `index.html` and `index2.html`. The difference is, `index2.html` doesn't have the redirecting Javascript code.

Now redirect the people from the Mobile Version to `index2.html` at your Desktop Site.

That is, in solution **TWO**, the flow can be like this:

User → Desktop Site (`index.html`) → Mobile Site → Desktop Site (`index2.hml`)

Here you can see, the user first comes to the Desktop Site, in `index.html` and automatically redirected to the Mobile Site. But the user then clicks to see the Desktop Version. There you should provide the link to `index2.html`, and then the user is not redirected automatically as the script is missing in `index2.html`